# How to scroll ScrollView and RecyclerView on fragment Resume

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-scrollview

I've faced a problem during my app development, that I need to save scroll position when leave fragment. Obviously, ScrollView can be scrolled to position with scrollTo() or smoothScrollBy(), and RecyclerView by scrollTo(position). And it works, if I test it by binding to buttons. Or on resume when I pause and then start application back. But  when I just go to the same fragment through in-app logic, there are no actions done.

Can anyone tell, what's the problem and possible solutions?

P.S.: Alternatively, can someone suggest the way to open picture with downloading from internet by url with just overlapping fragment without going to next one? Or it's only possible with alert dialog?

Comment: put your logic in onResume Method.

Comment: @DhruvSakariya I've already done that. But this logic works only when I roll-up application and open it back, not when I launch needed fragment